# AWS S3 - Copy objects from one bucket to another using pre-signurl

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to copy an object from one bucket to another, using pre-signed URL with both buckets, one pre-signed URL generated with `getObject` permission, while the other one with `putObject` permission.

I want to avoid downloading the objects using HTTP `GET` and uploading using the HTTP `PUT`, I want it to be as the usual way of copying objects between buckets (processed and executed within Amazon services).